# Within c++ function, pointer vs indexed array

Tags: c++, optimization, pointers, compiler-construction, paging

This question is similar to what has been asked [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2857055/1273037) but I think memory paging is not considered. So, I am posing the similar question again here:

```
// version 1
int nums[100];
int* pNum = nums;
for(int i=0;i<100;i++,pNum++){
  foo(pNum);
}

// version 2
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
  foo(nums[i]);
}
```

Which version would be faster? Previously, it was said that generated assembly code would be very similar since both versions require incrementing the position of memory address but considering a very large array, would memory paging performance change significantly? Since one of them requires a type long shift but other one requires a shift from the base memory address of the array? I know it is very platform/compiler dependent but still want to know the common practice of people, especially working with large data types like image processing or scientific computing? Thanks.

Comment: Try timing both and see for yourself. But I warn that modern compilers are very capable of converting one form to the other. So it may be difficult to benchmark.

Comment: You should not be worrying about minor details like this.  The compiler is smart enough to optimize this no matter how you write it.  Moreover, micro-optimizations like this are almost universally a waste of time; there's usually a much bigger source of inefficiency.

Comment: Actually, this was an interview question and I have said something along the lines of @templatetypedef but I think it really matters for chip-set makers.

Comment: @Mysticial, does it make sense if I try both version when compiler optimization is off?

Comment: @tartar Definitely not. Without optimizations, the compiler intentionally does stupid things to make it compile fast and debuggable, but at a massive cost to performance.

Comment: TBH, I've actually played with this particular optimization before. And there is no clear winner. They aren't the same, but neither is always faster. It gets interesting when you're incrementing multiple pointers. The first version has more increments, but the second version has indirect addressing and more register pressure. I've seen differences of up to 50%. But as mentioned, it's extremely environment dependent on both hardware and compiler. I'd consider it as a micro-optimization that's too difficult to bother with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general consensus is that for primitive types, there is no difference.  Most compilers will generate the exact same code for this (presumably you meant `foo(*pNum)`).

Comment: and if it doesn't generate the same code, I would imagine it's more likely to "mess up" on version 1 since it's not a typical way to write code and makes use of pointers, which compilers do occasionally have trouble with.

Comment: Do you consider cache misses / memory paging? Let say pNum currently points to the address base_address+10*sizeof(int), in this case, maybe CPU may think caching from base_address+10*sizeof(int) to 30*sizeof(int) would be a good idea. However for case of array with index, there is no hint of which part of array is processed?

Comment: Most compilers have an option to output the asm code (-S on gcc, for example). gcc with -O1 generates *exactly* the same code for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

> I know it is very platform/compiler dependent

Exactly

> but still want to know the common practice of people, especially working with large data types like image processing or scientific computing? Thanks.

Both practices are common, as is using vectors and iterators.  You're worrying about something that's overwhelmingly likely to be irrelevant.  Use whatever best expresses the way you're mentally visualising the algorithm, so it's easier to maintain and evolve correctly.